# Is it possible to get the car location including which level it is in a building?

Tags: google-maps, navigation, mapbox-android, android-auto, parking

Is there any possibility to get the car parked location also including the building floor information in android?

For example, if you are in a multilevel parking garage this information might be of some use.

Is there any current available method to do something like this?

Normally, Google map shows the location where the car is parked, but does not show any information regarding which floor it is at in a multilevel structure/building.

Comment: Are you using any particular API?

Comment: @user202729
 currently I'm trying with google map.